# How to replace 2 queries with except

Tags: sql, postgresql, except

I have two queries:

```
SELECT 
      users.id, 
      users.gender, 
      users.status, 
      users.icon_id, 
      users.image_name, 
      coords.lat, 
      coords.lng, 
      users.mess_count 
FROM 
    users 
INNER JOIN 
    coords ON users.id = coords.user_id
```

then I select blocked users:

```
SELECT 
      first_user, 
      second_user 
FROM 
    blocks 
WHERE 
    first_user = $1 OR second_user = $1
```

From first table I need to select all users which has coordinates and not blocked, I also need some public information(gender and etc.). Then because I need two side blocking. I have to select is user blocked him, or he was blocked by that user. So $1 is current user, and I select is my id in `block` table, if it is - I exclude another user from first query.

Then using string operations in my programming language I transform my string to exclude results I get from second query.

I probably can do it with `EXCEPT`, but I can't do it, because I have only 2 column selected with second query, and  I need much more, in final result: `users.id, users.gender, users.status, users.icon_id, users.image_name, coords.lat, coords.lng, users.mess_count` .

Comment: Are $1 and $2 usernames or users id?

Comment: @frlan It is users id.

Comment: You need more detail in your business logic.  For example, The first query only returns data for ***one*** user per record, but the second query has ***two*** users per record.  Do you want to exclude all records from *query 1* if the `users.id` appears in *either* column in *query 2*?  Please be specific, and ideally please show example input and output data.

Comment: @MatBailie I just updated my question. Need your comment, is it understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, the only mildly compromising factor is that I *believe* you want to exclude users that appear in *either* of two columns in the `blocks` table.

SQL traditionally has weaker performance with `OR` logic, which the following query attempts to work around.   *(In part due to its ability to make better use of indexes)*

```
SELECT 
  users.id, 
  users.gender, 
  users.status, 
  users.icon_id, 
  users.image_name, 
  coords.lat, 
  coords.lng, 
  users.mess_count 
FROM 
  users 
INNER JOIN
  coords
    ON users.id=coords.user_id
WHERE
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE first_user  = users.id AND second_user = $1)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM blocks WHERE second_user = users.id AND first_user  = $1)
```

Depending on the version of PostgreSQL, the optimiser *may* be less efficient with correlated sub-queries, such as those I have used above.  In such a case, the following may be more performant still.  *(It still avoids using **OR**.)*

```
SELECT 
  users.id, 
  users.gender, 
  users.status, 
  users.icon_id, 
  users.image_name, 
  coords.lat, 
  coords.lng, 
  users.mess_count 
FROM 
  users 
INNER JOIN
  coords
    ON users.id=coords.user_id
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT first_user  AS user_id FROM blocks WHERE second_user = $1
   UNION
   SELECT second_user AS user_id FROM blocks WHERE first_user  = $1
)
  AS blocks
    ON blocks.users_id = users.id
WHERE
  blocks.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: what do you think about `NOT IN` which @Vitap Ramdevputra suggested?

Comment: @SlowHarry - It's functionally the same as the `NOT EXISTS` method, but in many RDBMS it can be slower, depending on your data.  This is increasingly true the higher the number of items (blockers) returned by the sub-query.  I've not used PostGres as much as I have used others, but I have not yet found a situation where `NOT IN` has performed better than `NOT EXISTS`, even when they've both been supported by the most useful possible indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You could left join with the `blocks` table, then use the `is null` check.

```
SELECT 
      users.id, 
      users.gender, 
      users.status, 
      users.icon_id, 
      users.image_name, 
      coords.lat, 
      coords.lng, 
      users.mess_count 
FROM 
      users 
INNER JOIN coords ON users.id=coords.user_id
LEFT JOIN blocks ON users.id = blocks.first_user OR users.id = blocks.second_user
WHERE blocks.first_user IS NULL
```

Comment: This query doesn't use the ***$1*** parameter.

Comment: What is `$1` parameter?

Comment: Look at the OP, the 2nd query has two references to ***$1***

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, I wrote the query using `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT 
  users.id, 
  users.gender, 
  users.status, 
  users.icon_id, 
  users.image_name, 
  coords.lat, 
  coords.lng, 
  users.mess_count 
FROM 
  users 
  INNER JOIN coords ON users.id=coords.user_id
  Where 
   users.id NOT IN (SELECT first_user FROM blocks WHERE first_user=$1)
   AND
   users.id NOT IN (SELECT second_user FROM blocks WHERE second_user=$1)
```